Is Bulk Push Notification available for New HTTP v1 APIs after migrating from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 for .Net core 6 application
My application is in .Net core 6, C#.
I have migrated Existing FCM legacy APIs to New HTTP v1 APIs.
But I have a question, Is Bulk Push notification is possible for this New APIs?
For existing APIs, I have implemented Topic to subscribe and then send the Bulk Push Notification.
Existing URLs were
FCM topic Url - "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd"
Old FCM Url - "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
New FCM HTTP v1 URLs
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dcbmbuat/messages:send"
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
How to implement Bulk Push Notification for New FCM HTTP v1 APIs?
Is there any online resource available?
I checked the official website of firebase, But I didn't find any proper dedicated answer to this problem.
